# Is there a performance penalty for passing "this" by value in Go methods?

Tags: c++, go

I'm exploring Go after 9 years of C++ development. In C++ it is a bad practice to pass function's arguments by value except variables of built-in types because of performance penalty: all fields of the argument will be copied and in most cases it will be a very costly operation.

Is this true for Go? It looks very expensive to pass "this" by value only to assign "const" semantic to the method. Is Go compiler smart enough to prevent variable from being copied before first modification? Why isn't passing "this" by value an anti-pattern in Go as it is in C/C++?

Comment: Your C++ knowledge is outdated: passing by value is actually fine in many circumstances (and *always* OK for lots of types even if they’re not builtins). Here’s a primer: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: Please show us the code you're worried about. In Go you can pass structs via pointers only. If you want a copy, you need to create a function that actually copies.

Comment: @janislaw Not true: http://play.golang.org/p/w5_6_w8JAn

Comment: I've learned my lesson. Also, this: http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nice article, but as you can see there, optimization will be made for rvalues only. There will be a real copy in the case of lvalues. So passing arguments by value is still a bad practice in general.

Comment: @Pavel It depends. Often you actually make a copy internally. In all those cases passing by value is also good. In fact, the linked article doesn’t primarily talk about lvalue references at all. I agree that *in general*  passing by value is a bad idea, but in modern C++ we need to add that passing by reference *in general* is *also* a bad idea.

Comment: Making a code base 150% as big for a performance optimization is not general good practice. Doing it in places where performance and memory usage are a big concern, is ok.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers are good but in my opinion, there's some information missing.

Receivers in Go are just syntactic sugar, as demonstrated by the following [code](http://play.golang.org/p/NtwQpZu580):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Something struct {
    Value int
}

func (s *Something) ChangeValue(n int) {
    s.Value = n
}

func main() {
    o := new(Something)             // o is of type *Something
    fmt.Println(o.Value)            // Prints 0
    o.ChangeValue(8)                // Changes o.Value to 8
    fmt.Println(o.Value)            // Prints 8
    (*Something).ChangeValue(o, 16) // Same as calling o.ChangeValue(16)
    fmt.Println(o.Value)            // Prints 16
}
```

Based on this, consider what would happen if the receiver of `ChangeValue` was a value of type `Something` instead of a pointer to one...

That's right! You could never actually mutate `o`'s `Value` field through this method. Most of the time, you use pointer receivers to do encapsulation.

Answer (score 6):

"this" in Go is called a [receiver](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations). Yes, it may be very expensive to use a non pointer receiver only to emulate a "const" semantics. But Go dropped the "const" modifier for good reasons. Thus, it's probably not a good idea to take over that specific language design decision at the cost of unnecessary copying - in the case of anything bigger than few machine words.

BTW, the terminology difference between "this" or "self" and "receiver" implies it has also different semantics. IIRC, one cannot change the value of "this" or "self" in some other languages, but in Go, the receiver is just another function parameter (actually the first one from the compiler's point of view).

That said, this is the reason I discourage writing methods in which the receiver variable is named `this` or `self`. It's misleading for people used to some other languages.

A completely made-up example illustrating hopefully the idea:

```
func (n *node) walk(f func(*node)) {
        for n != nil {
                f(n)
                n = n.next
        }
}
```

Comment: I believe the receiver operates the same way in Python, but by convention they call it "self" as well. I don't understand why it would be confusing to call your receiver "this" or "self"... Even if someone treats a receiver just like they would treat "this" in Java, there's no danger AFAICT... I do it all the time so as to make my code more readable for myself and others coming from other OO langs.

Comment: Consider: `i int`, `p *T`, `s string`, `f *os.File`, `flag bool`, `n *node`, `r *root`. Now rename all the variables (assuming no redeclarations as a result) to `blah`. Would you argue it's _"more readable"_? I don't believe so. Naming every receiver a same name instead of giving it a hinting (ie. reader helpfull) name is not _"more readable"_ to me, but less readable. It's only a habit from languages which force that. But Go doesn't, so there is no reason to keep oneself restricted where the restriction doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

I would say your C++ knowledge will translate fine into Go about what is expensive as a function argument (passing structs by value) and what isn't (builtin types, eg int).

The major difference would be the reference types, slices, `map`s and `channel`s.  These, though they appear to be passed by value (you don't need to use a pointer) are actually passed by reference, so don't in general use a pointer to a slice, map or channel.

`string`s are also special - they are reference types under the hood, but they are also immutable, so pass them around directly.

As for the specific case of `this` or the receiver as it is called in Go - same rules apply (note that you can have builtin types as a receiver unlike C++), and I don't think the compiler is smart enough to avoid copies, so use a pointer for large structs.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the size of the receiver. If the receiver is less than a few dozen bytes, copying it might actually be cheaper than the pointer chasing (extra memory accesses) that would be required if you passed a pointer. Also, using a pointer makes it somewhat more likely that the struct will be allocated on the heap, putting an extra burden on the garbage collector.

In Go, the copy is always a byte-by-byte copy, so the cost depends only on the size of the struct. In C++ it might call a copy constructor, which could potentially take a lot of time.

So, except for really big objects, just use whatever kind of receiver makes the most sense based on the semantics of the method and consistency with the rest of your API.