# What is the difference between parameter and receiver

Tags: go

I am following a Go tutorial and am stuck as I cant understand a particular method signature:

```
func (p *Page) save() error {
    filename := p.Title + ".txt"
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}
```

The docs explain this as follows:

> This method's signature reads: "This is a method named save that takes as its receiver p, a pointer to Page . It takes no parameters, and returns a value of type error."

I cant understand what the receiver is.  I would read this as it being a parameter but then I would expect a parameter to be in `save()`.

Comment: If you're familiar with C++, Java, or JavaScript, then the "receiver" is the equivalent of `this`. If you're familiar with Perl or Python, then it's the equivalent of the first argument to a method (usually `self` in Python code). If you're not familiar with any of those, then . . . are you familiar with any other object-oriented languages?

Comment: The syntax is very confusing to me.  I use php and python.  So go doesnt have classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: what is the difference between a method receiver and parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159457/go-what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-receiver-and-parameter)

Comment: Go does not have classes. The receiver is a pointer to Page - likely a struct you've initialized and want to do something to(in this case, it appears, saving the Body of Page into a file which is named the same as Title of the Page.). You can't use this function on something that isn't of type Page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The receiver is the object on what you declare your method.

When want to add a method to an object, you use this syntax.

ex: http://play.golang.org/p/5n-N_Ov6Xz

Comment: So this is like the context on which the method belongs?

Comment: Exactly. As ruakh said, it is similar to c++ 'this'. It is the current object or pointer to the current object (depending if you put a '*' or not)

Answer (score 31):

The receiver is just a special case of a parameter. Go provides syntactic sugar to *attach* methods to types by declaring the first parameter as a receiver.

For instance:

```
func (p *Page) save() error
```

reads *"attach a method called `save` that returns an `error` to the type `*Page`"*, as opposed to declaring:

```
func save(p *Page) error
```

that would read *"declare a function called `save` that takes one parameter of type `*Page` and returns an `error`"*

As proof that it's only syntactic sugar you can try out the following code:

```
p := new(Page)
p.save()
(*Page).save(p)
```

Both last lines represent exactly the same method call.

Also, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328868/532430).

Comment: Out of interest why is this more preferable to enclosing the methods in a class and calling the method like class->func without having to pass the type also?  I understand what its doing now, just not why?  For example in java you would simple do p->save() without having to pass the object in. (maybe thats a whole other question!!)

Comment: There are no classes in Go, only types. You could ask the same question about Java, though. Imagine you could take out all methods of a java class and call them procedurally by passing `this` as a parameter explicitly. Same thing.