# How do I use this function in Golang?

Tags: go

Hey I'm new to Go syntax. How would I use this function? The part that is throwing me is the pointer at the beginning of the function declaration?

```
func (p *Pointer) FunctionName(arg string) error {
  dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(arg))
  err := dec.Decode(&p)
  return err
}
```

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/4

Comment: What are you meaning with “reusing”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between parameter and receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932722/what-is-the-difference-between-parameter-and-receiver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FunctionName` is a [method](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) on `*Pointer`.

If you are asking how to use the code on arbitrary types and not just a `*Pointer`, then write it as a function:

```
func FunctionName(v interface{}, arg string) error {
  dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(arg))
  err := dec.Decode(v)
  return err
}
```

Assuming that `p` is a variable of type `*Pointer`, then call it like this:

```
FunctionName(p, "{... JSON text here }")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Go struct types can contain methods, and that is what you have here. Say I have the following code:

```
type Foo struct {
    Something string
}

func (f * Foo) PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println(f.Something)
}
```

I cannot invoke `PrintSomething` directly, I must invoke it by using a variable of type `Foo`. Example:

```
f := Foo{
    Something: "Something",
}

f.PrintSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a method definition. The way to use it is

```
var p Pointer
/* or */
p := new(Pointer)

p.FunctionName(arg)
```

Comment: This references a `NewPointer` func that may or may not exist but is unexplained and critical to the answer. This would be more instructive for a completely new Go user (which this would appear to be based on the question) if you just used `p := new(Pointer)` or `p := &Pointer{}`

Comment: Hate to be this guy after you edited it, but you should really avoid using the `new()` builtin function. Its best used (and should only be used) in very specific situations where you need an immediate pointer to a primitive type. I would go with @Adrian's latter approach of `p := &Pointer{}`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwardShawIV what's your reasoning for that?