# Difference between a method receiver as pointer or not

Tags: methods, go

Why don't I have to define PrintValue() as a pointer receiver (*One) to be able to print "hello"?

```
package main
import "fmt"


type One struct{
    a string
}
func (o *One)AssignValue(){
    o.a = "hello"
}
func (o One)PrintValue(){
    fmt.Println(o.a)
}

func main() {
    one := One{}
    one.AssignValue()
    one.PrintValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `one` is already of type `One`. The instantiation syntax

```
t := One{}
```

creates a **value** of type `One` while the form

```
p := &One{}
```

creates a **pointer to a value** of type `One`.

This means that nothing is to be done when calling `t.PrintValue` as the receiver type (`One`) is already the same as the type of `t` (`One` as well).

When calling `p.PrintValue` the compiler automatically converts an addressable variable to its pointer form because the receiver type (`One`) is not equal to the type of `p` (`*One`). So the expression

```
p.PrintValue()
```

is converted to

```
(*p).PrintValue()
```

There is also a conversion necessary when calling `t.AssignValue` as this method has a pointer receiver but we're supplying a value. This is also done automatically by the compiler where possible.

From [the spec on calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. **If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()**

This means the expression

```
t.AssignValue()
```

is converted to

```
(&t).AssignValue()
```

Note that this is not always possible. For example when returning a value from a function:

```
func NewOne(s string) One { return One{s} }

NewOne("foo").AssignValue() // Not possible

x := NewOne("foo")
x.AssignValue() // Possible, automatically converted
```

Comment: So this is "behind the scene magic" ... A bit confusing if you ask me.

Comment: If however AssignValue() isn't defined as a pointer receiver then PrintValue() prints an empty string.  Why is that then?

Comment: Because then your `o` in `AssignValue` is copied and your modification is only done on the copy.

Comment: ok, this has  been helpful.  I think this behavior is not highlighted enough in beginners books and examples.  A bad habit for people coming from dynamic languages (like myself) is to try an recreate a class (Python) in Go and expect it behaves the same.
Thanks!

Comment: this answer is actually wrong: you don't need a pointer receiver because in your case the copy of `o` your `PrintValue` sees has its `a` field set set to "hello". Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326185/is-there-a-performance-penalty-for-passing-this-by-value-in-go-methods/15328868#15328868) for further info about receivers.

Comment: @tomwilde Err. What? What is wrong? Where? I don't see what you mean.

Comment: the receiver of `PrintValue` is not a pointer and won't be implicitly converted to one.

Comment: @tomwilde You're right of course, I have updated my answer. Totally misread the code...