# what's this part of code in exec.start means?

Tags: go

I read the code of exec.Start,and there some part confusing me. (*Cmd).stdin/out/err in the []F,what's the meaning of (*Cmd).stdXX?

```
   291      type F func(*Cmd) (*os.File, error)
   292      for _, setupFd := range []F{(*Cmd).stdin, (*Cmd).stdout, (*Cmd).stderr} {
   293          fd, err := setupFd(c)
   294          if err != nil {
   295              c.closeDescriptors(c.closeAfterStart)
   296              c.closeDescriptors(c.closeAfterWait)
   297              return err
   298          }
   299          c.childFiles = append(c.childFiles, fd)
   300      }
```

Comment: Dereferencing `Cmd` which is a pointer so that `(*Cmd)` is an object and calling a mathod on that object.  Dead simple, not wirth an answer.

Comment: I do not think this is that easy: `Cmd` is a type, not a variable name. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very Nice find, I did not know that idiom before. I will try to break it down.
First We have exec.Cmd

```
type exec.Cmd struct { ... }
```

`*Cmd` has 3 many methods including `stdin` `stdout` `stderr`

```
func (c *Cmd) stdin() (f *os.File, err error) {...}
func (c *Cmd) stdout() (f *os.File, err error) {...}
func (c *Cmd) stderr() (f *os.File, err error) {...}
```

Now I want to call all these functions and do the same set of operations on each of them but I don't want to create another method because there are too many shared variable to pass by arguments.

The first solution would be to just copy / paste the code 3 times. not nice.

The second is to loop over an array of *Functors*. The Functor type would be `func(c*Cmd)(f *os.File, err error)` so we declare it as

```
type F (c *Cmd) (f *os.File, err error)
```

now we can create the array of functors. But how to select a `*Cmd` method ? simply using

`(*Cmd).<name of method>`

So it would be `(*Cmd).stdin, (*Cmd.stdout), (*Cmd).stderr`
and we can use them as An array

```
[]F{ (*Cmd).stdin, (*Cmd.stdout), (*Cmd).stderr }
```

we just need to call them now

```
for _, setupFd := range []F{(*Cmd).stdin, (*Cmd).stdout, (*Cmd).stderr} {
    fd, err := setupFd(c)
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: [They are just plain old regular functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15328868/532430) Receivers are just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting idiom I have never encountered before. The code takes `*Cmd`'s methods as functions and calls them in order on `c`. Here is a simpler code example that shows how it works: http://play.golang.org/p/XwuYD_9uGs.

That code could as well be written as `for` body called with three different `stdXX`, but that would be repetitive and bug-prone, so the author decided instead to apply three methods in a cycle.